# How to get attributes / object of React child component in parent component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-functional-component

I have created FC [say child component for my example] containing address fields [couple of input boxes and SelectItems], when this FC is called from another component [parent], i need to access the values of input boxes and select items added by user.

Can you help me by giving simple example of say 1 text box in child component when called by parent via Functional Component style [TypeScript]

Here is my example code of child component having two Inputs and a SelectItem

```
return (
    <>
          <Accordion varient={'grouped'} expanded theme={theme}
          items={[
            {
              content: 
              <>

              <Input label='Address Line 1' fullWidth={true} type={''} startAdornment={""} endAdornment={""}  
                  onChange={(e) => setAddressL1(e)} onBlur={handleChangeAddrL1} id={''} theme={theme} dynamic={false} />
             
                <Input label='City' fullWidth={false} type={''} startAdornment={""} endAdornment={""}                onChange={(e) => setCity(e)} onBlur={handleChangeCity} id={''} theme={theme} dynamic={false} /> 
             
            
              <Select label='State' theme={theme} items={states} value = {stateCode} sxProps={{ m: 2, width: 100 }} ref={inputRef}
                    onChange={handleChange1} ></Select> 
                
             
              <Button text= 'Verify Address' ></Button>

              </>,
              isExpanded: true,
              key: "string",
              subtitle: `${addressL1} ${addressL2} ${city} ${stateCode} ${county} ${zipCode}`, 
              title: AccordionTitle,
              actionBtn: <></>
            }
           ]}
          /> 

    </>  
   )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you want to achieve, there are two scenario to deal with your request.
**First**
You can pass data from child component to parent component using `navigation.navigate('RouterName', {/* your params here */})` from the child component triggered by onClick or onPress event. Let say the function is moveTo, then you will have this in the child component:

```
const moveTo = () => {
//Logics here
...
navigate('/yourUrl/', { state: { id: 7, color: 'green' } });
}
```

Then in the parent component, you grab the data of color like this:

```
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom'

const getdataFromChild = ({route,navigate}) => {
  return (
    <div>
        {route.params.state}
    </div>
  )
}

export default getDataFromChild
```

This is only possible when you are triggering the navigation from child to parent, otherwise move to option Second.

**Option Second:**
If there is no click event to trigger a navigation from child to parent or parent to child, then you need to use React redux. So you have to create a store of that data and share it throughout your app so it may be accessed in every component that needs it. The documentation for redux is also on [medium](https://medium.com/geekculture/redux-with-reacts-functional-components-272f1008ee69)
or go straight to the [official documentation of react redux](https://react-redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started) to get the informations from the source

Comment: thanks Himmels, as I am not navigating pages [router would not work then], your second option seems more interesting i will give it a try but for current project i dont have liberty to add Redux in it.          for someone looking for options i used useRef hook to pass data between parent and child. this link helped me to showcase the scenario                                                                            https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60554808/react-useref-with-typescript-and-functional-component

Comment: @kashifayyaz Ok well done, if the data passed from child to parent is for the lifetime of the component only then yes, you got a good approach.